# PowerShell cannot CD into path in .NET Core container in Ubuntu 16.06

Tags: .net, linux, powershell, ubuntu, ssh

I've setup a .NET Core w/ PowerShell on Ubuntu 16.06 for testing purposes via Digital Ocean.

After successfully logging into root. It gives me the PowerShell command line.

I'm setting up an SSH key so I can have an application have access to the system. I'm aware that the directory for **authorized_keys** is located in

```
~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Logically I do the following command:

```
cd .ssh/authorized_keys
```

The error I get back is the following:

```
cd : Cannot find path 'authorized_keys' because it does not exist.
```

**NOTE:** I am able to access the **.ssh** directory and list its content using **ls**. The results tell me that there is indeed an **authorized_keys** folder within **.ssh**

My wonderful issue:

```
PS /root> cd .ssh
PS /root/.ssh> ls
authorized_keys
PS /root/.ssh> cd authorized_keys
cd : Cannot find path 'authorized_keys' because it does not exist.
```

My goal:

To enter the directory to create via **nano** a public key (.pub)

Comment: I believe `authorized_keys` is a file, not a directory. Learn to use `ls -l filespec` to see full information about files/dirs. A dir entry will have `d` as the first char, while a file will have `-` as the first char. Read elsewhere about meaning of `rwxr--r--` and similar. Good luck.

Comment: while you can edit/append authorized_keys file, the typical way to have it updated is automatically, when you 1. ssh user@remotehost 2. ssh replies enter password for user@remote host 3. ssh replies, i don't recognize this host (it's not in my authorized_keys file). OK to connect (Y/N). 4. When you type Y, the pub key for the remote host is added to the authorized_keys file. If someone has sent you a pub key file, then `cat remotehost.pub >> ./.ssh/authorized_keys` should let you avoid steps 2-4 above. So please so trying to `cd authorized_keys`. You should remove that from your Q. ....

Comment: Sorry, just noticed you said "The results tell me that there is indeed an authorized_keys folder within .ssh" ? Doublechecking the ssh doc. Please edit your Q to show output of `ls -la ./ssh`. Good luck.

Comment: ssh doc say `authorized_keys` is (should be) a file. rename the `authorized_keys` dir like `auth_keys_sav`. and then rerun your `ssh` stuff to see it it autocreates the file. Good luck.

Comment: I ended up wiping everything within the `.ssh` and I created an `authorized_keys` file with everything I needed. Though I did learn some new tricks with `ls` and more about `authorized_keys` via documentation, etc. Thanks everyone!